# Get terms lists from post->ID, is it possible?

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

I have a post type called "portfolio", and many taxonomies "design", "code" etc...
For each taxonomy i have terms (ex: inside design : photoshop, illustrator etc...)

and for each term i have many posts.

How to retrieve dynamicaly terms, and taxonomy of a post?

The function get_the_term_list( $id, $taxonomy, $before, $sep, $after ) does not fit my need because i need to have the taxonomy name in advance.

Is it possible to get terms attached to a post from post->ID? and also get taxonomy name i registered this post?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you you are looking for:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms